# XSL I need to run a loop if a certain variable equals a specific value?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new to XML and XSL and am having trouble. I have scoured the internet and tried nearly everything I saw and I just couldn't get it to work. What I need is to output the name of all the people whose address is a shipping address.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PurchaseOrders>
  <PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" OrderDate="1999-10-20">
    <Address Type="Shipping">
      <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
      <Street>123 Maple Street</Street>
    </Address>
    <Address Type="Billing">
      <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
      <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
    </Address>
  </PurchaseOrder>

  <PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99505" OrderDate="1999-10-22">
    <Address Type="Shipping">
      <Name>Cristian Osorio</Name>
      <Street>456 Main Street</Street>
    </Address>
    <Address Type="Billing">
      <Name>Cristian Osorio</Name>
      <Street>456 Main Street</Street>
    </Address>
  </PurchaseOrder>
```

and here is my xml so far - keep in mind I have no idea what I'm doing! :) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Customer Info</title>      
      </head>  
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
          <tr bgcolor="yellow">
            <th>Customer</th>        
          </tr>  
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates />        
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
     </html> 
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PurchaseOrder">
       <tr>
           <xsl:for-each select="Address">
              <xsl:value-of select=" .[@Type="Shipping">
                 <td>
             <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
         </td>
         </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
     </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've tried everything from including an if statement to changing the code around but nothing seems to work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A good start at a Q. make it great, by editing in your expected output, given your test input. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/PurchaseOrders">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Customer Info</title>      
        </head>  
        <body>
            <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr bgcolor="yellow">
                    <th>Customer</th>        
                </tr>  
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="PurchaseOrder/Address[@Type='Shipping']"/>        
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Address">
    <tr>
        <td>
             <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the filtering done with `xsl:apply-templates`; this eliminates the need for conditionals later on.

Comment: That makes it so much easier too. I knew it was something easy that I was just overlooking.  Thank you!!